# Update locked dataframe called as follows secondpackage::dataframe1 in R environment using bindenv functions?

Tags: r, environment

I am developping a R package, for example called `myfirstpackage`.
Inside this package, I load a `secondpackage` from which I use a dataframe as follows  `secondpackage::dataframe1`.
I call it like this, several times, inside `myfirstpackage`.

I would like to be able to modify `secondpackage::dataframe1` in my main script to add rows to this dataframe.
I want to do it just before being called from functions of `myfirstpackage`.
In another words, I want to update a dataframe from a package loaded in the environment

```
secondpackage::dataframe1 <- rbind(secondpackage::dataframe1,aCustomDataframe2)
```

Is this possible using tricks from the environment like unlockBinding ?

So then `secondpackage::dataframe1`  is update everywhere in the next functions that are calling it  ? Possible ?

Comment: I may misunderstand this, but this does not sound like a good idea to me. Even if it is possible, a user who wants to use `secondpackage::dataframe1` may understandably expect that no other packages are altering it.

Comment: I also developped the secondpackage :) so it's fine someone modifiy dataframe1.